# UI view update when Fragments are stacked in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

AM not so good in android Fragments. We need a proper solution to solve my problem. In mother activity I've fragment A,B,C. Every fragments comes after another . First A fragment is shown and after some user input we replace it with Fragment B and Fragment A is stacked. After B is done we replace it with C Fragment and B is stacked after A. I can go back to previous fragment to Edit the Data so we are saving the user inputs.

But when I go back to Fragments always I can get all data but only can update Fragment A UI view . I can't update any ui view in Fragment B and C .

Code snippests for different portions

abid hasan: getting current object for updating

City currentCity = cityManager.getCurrentCity();

```
    updateViews(currentCity);
```

checking data for this object and updating views .

```
 public static void updateViews(City currentCity){

    Log.d(TAG , "updating views for city... "+currentCity.getCityName());



    if (currentCity.getCityAccommodations().size() > 0 || currentCity.getCityLocations().size() > 0 || currentCity.getHotels().size() > 0) {
        viewModifyLayoutHotels.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        deSelectAccommodationRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        viewModifyLayoutHotels.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (currentCity.cityFlights.size() > 0) {
        viewModifyLayoutFlights.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        deSelectFlyRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        viewModifyLayoutFlights.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if(currentCity.getFlightClass().equals("")){

        viewModifyLayoutFlights.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        deSelectFlyRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    }else {

        viewModifyLayoutFlights.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (currentCity.getActivities().size() > 0) {

        viewModifyLayoutActivities.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        deSelectActivityRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        viewModifyLayoutActivities.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


}
```

on back press event from the successor fragment’s onDestroy()  method and getting that object from manager and updating views

```
public static void updateViews(City currentCity){

    Log.d(TAG , "updating views for city... "+currentCity.getCityName());



    if (currentCity.getCityAccommodations().size() > 0 || currentCity.getCityLocations().size() > 0 || currentCity.getHotels().size() > 0) {
        viewModifyLayoutHotels.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        deSelectAccommodationRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        viewModifyLayoutHotels.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (currentCity.cityFlights.size() > 0) {
        viewModifyLayoutFlights.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        deSelectFlyRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        viewModifyLayoutFlights.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if(currentCity.getFlightClass().equals("")){

        viewModifyLayoutFlights.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        deSelectFlyRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    }else {

        viewModifyLayoutFlights.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (currentCity.getActivities().size() > 0) {

        viewModifyLayoutActivities.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        deSelectActivityRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        viewModifyLayoutActivities.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


}
```

before onDestroy() call I reset Those view to initial state from onStart() method

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    Log.d(MakeATripStepFourFragment.TAG , "calling onStart from "+TAG);
    MakeATripFragmentFirstTime.destinationTextView.setText("Select experts for your trip");
    resetCityPreferencesViews();
    super.onStart();
}

public static void resetCityPreferencesViews() {

    MakeATripStepFourFragment.deSelectFlyRadioButton.setChecked(true);
    MakeATripStepFourFragment.selectFlyRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    MakeATripStepFourFragment.deSelectAccommodationRadioButton.setChecked(true);
    MakeATripStepFourFragment.selectAccommodationRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    MakeATripStepFourFragment.deSelectActivityRadioButton.setChecked(true);
    MakeATripStepFourFragment.selectActivityRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    MakeATripStepFourFragment.viewModifyLayoutFlights.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    MakeATripStepFourFragment.viewModifyLayoutHotels.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    MakeATripStepFourFragment.viewModifyLayoutActivities.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

for that city for those UI is not updating I use a LocalBroadcast call to Separate UI thread updating

```
if (!childFragment.onBackPressed()) {
            // child Fragment was unable to handle the task
            // It could happen when the child Fragment is last last leaf of a chain
            // removing the child Fragment from stack
            Log.d(MakeATripStepFourFragment.TAG , "this fragment.. "+childFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());

            if(childFragment instanceof MakeATripStepFourFragment){
                Log.d(MakeATripStepFourFragment.TAG ,"lets try it out");
                if (cityManager.hasNextCity()) {
                    City currentCity = cityManager.getNextCity();
                    MakeATripFragmentFirstTime.destinationTextView.setText(currentCity.getCityName());

                    Log.d(MakeATripStepFourFragment.TAG, "updating radioButton with city.. "+currentCity.getCityName());
                    Intent intent = new Intent("update_radio-button");
                    intent.putExtra(MakeATripStepFourFragment.TAG,currentCity);

                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(((MakeATripStepFourFragment) childFragment).getActivity()).sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            }
            childFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();

        }

        // either this Fragment or its child handled the task
        // either way we are successful and done here
        return true;
    }
```

and in the broadcast receiver   i call the updateViews() method

```
 private BroadcastReceiver updatePreferences = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        City currentCity = (City) intent.getSerializableExtra(TAG);
        Log.d(TAG , "recived call with city..."+currentCity.getCityName());
        ExpertSelectorFragment.resetCityPreferencesViews();
        updateViews(currentCity);
    }
};
```

What maybe the solution I have to know . Please wanting perfect suggestion

Here on a button click looping through the city objects and adding fragment for them , if all city traversing completed then proceed to the next fragmet

```
  case R.id.next_fragment_destination_button:

            if (!cityManager.hasNextCity()) {
                Log.d("status = ", "all city explored : " + cityManager.currentCityIndex);

                cityManager.currentCityIndex = 0;
                /*LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mActivity).unregisterReceiver(messageReceiver);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mActivity).unregisterReceiver(accomodationAllPreferenceReciver);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mActivity).unregisterReceiver(activitiesForCityPreferenceReciver);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mActivity).unregisterReceiver(updatePreferences);*/
                setDataToGetExperts(cityManager.getAllCities().size());


            } else {

                Log.d("status = ", "going to next : " + cityManager.currentCityIndex);
                Log.d(TAG, "current city size " + cityManager.getCurrentCity().toString());

                cityManager.getNextCity();

                //we have a next city
                MakeATripStepFourFragment fragment = MakeATripStepFourFragment.newInstance(0);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                // Store the Fragment in stack
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment ,TAG);
                transaction.commit();
            }
            break;
```

Comment: @WaqarYounis posted. Please check

Comment: where you add fragments in MainActivity(Your Activity)??

Comment: use eventbus for dynamically update fragments....